# Dar estética de mensaje de correo enviado a través de php

Tags: php, html, email

Tengo una pagina web en la cual hago el envió a través de un formulario haciendo uso de php funciona a la perfección y me llega el correo electrónico sin problema , pero ahora existe una duda el correo que llega esta demasiado simple a la vista (adjunto imagen)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Habría la posibilidad de al momento de armar el envió desde php el mensaje se le puede dar un mejor formato o incluir html?.

De antemano agradezco su tiempo y colaboración.

Comment: Sí se puede incluir HTML en un correo, pero cómo se verá depende del cliente de correo a donde llegue el correo.

Comment: Tienes algún ejemplo o guía para poder visualizar y plasmarlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se puede incluir HTML de una manera simple, con `headers` al momento de enviar el email, depende de que cliente de correo utilice el destinatario, ya que si el cliente de correo del destinatario no acepta HTML, el envío, puede verse afectado

```php
$to = "someone@domain.tld";
$subject = "Email con HTML";

$msg = "
<html>
<body>
<p>Mail con HTML</p>
</body>
</html>
";
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: <webmaster@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: myboss@example.com' . "\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

El `Content-Type` le dirá al servidor de destino que vamos a usar HTML para nuestro correo, el envío con `mail()` puede verse afectado si el servidor de destino no acepta HTML, además si no acepta HTML puede que el correo simplemente no se envíe o llegue con problemas con visualización